# Date Issue in Kendo UI when Filter Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

When we filter Kendo datagrid, use different types of operator like eq, and, or,
gt, lt etc. that's  work well in string and number. When we use date to match another date using eq operator does not work but gt,lt works.

This is my source code

```
dataSource: {
                       data: data,

                       schema: {
                           model: {
                               fields: {
                                   date: { type: "date"},
                                   id: { type: "string" },
                                   name: { type: "number" },
                                   account: { type: "number" }

                               }
                           }

                       },
                       sort: [ { field: "date", dir: "desc" }],

                       filter : [{
                                field: "date", operator: "eq", value: dateString

                                }],

                       pageSize: 30,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

probably your datestring is not being read has a date, so when it goes filter it throws a error.

Try to or use the format propertie in the grid

```
 columns   : [
    {
        field       : "Date",
        title       : "Date",
        format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}",
        filterable: {
            ui: "datepicker"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: In column i have used same format date that you mention .. this is my code  { field: "date", title: "Date" , format:"{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"  }.  I have also used same format data (MM-dd-yyyy)  dateString using equal operator (eq) to initial filter grid. Result will be same but gt and lt operator work well...